# Jquery Tablesorting Problem - Sort text column case-insensitively

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using a Jquery Tablesorter plugin for sorting a table.I want, when I sort the text column, jquery tablesorter consider the lowercase and uppercase text equally means sort text column case-insensitively.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various parts in the plugin code such at this at line 701:

```
return $.trim(s.toLowerCase());
```

where the values are all converted to lowerCase to avoid case difference problems. Although I think these are implanted nicely you should be able to modify these lines to adjust this. simple remove all toLowerCase methods. but ready them thoroughly before simply just deleting.